# Using Docker Buildkit on Google Cloud Build

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build, docker-buildkit

I'm trying to use BuildKit with Docker on Google Cloud Build so that I can eventually use the --secret flag.  I'm using [Build Enhancements for Docker](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) as a reference.

It works on my laptop when I use the following command: `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t hello-world:latest .`

When I run it on Cloud Build, I get the error  "docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental not found".

Any idea how to get this to work on Cloud Build?

Here is the setup (note: I'm not using the --secret flag yet):

Dockerfile:

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

FROM node:10.15.3-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && \
    apk add --no-cache tini

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

RUN chown -R node:node .

USER node

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:

  - id: 'Build'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [
      'build',
      '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/hello-world:latest',
      '.'
    ]
    env:
      - "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1"
```

Cloud Build Log:

```
starting build "xxxx"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://xxxxx
Copying gs://xxxxx...
/ [0 files][ 0.0 B/ 15.3 KiB] 
/ [1 files][ 15.3 KiB/ 15.3 KiB] 
Operation completed over 1 objects/15.3 KiB. 
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 digest: sha256:3ce0de94c925587ad30afb764af9bef89edeb62eb891b99694aedb086ee53f50
#2 name: "[internal] load .dockerignore"
#2 started: 2019-07-24 03:21:49.153855989 +0000 UTC
#2 completed: 2019-07-24 03:21:49.195969197 +0000 UTC
#2 duration: 42.113208ms
#2 transferring context: 230B done


#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 digest: sha256:82b0dcd17330313705522448d60a78d4565304d55c86f55b903b18877d612601
#1 name: "[internal] load build definition from Dockerfile"
#1 started: 2019-07-24 03:21:49.150042849 +0000 UTC
#1 completed: 2019-07-24 03:21:49.189628322 +0000 UTC
#1 duration: 39.585473ms
#1 transferring dockerfile: 445B done


#3 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental
#3 digest: sha256:401713457b113a88eb75a6554117f00c1e53f1a15beec44e932157069ae9a9a3
#3 name: "resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental"
#3 started: 2019-07-24 03:21:49.210803849 +0000 UTC
#3 completed: 2019-07-24 03:21:49.361743084 +0000 UTC
#3 duration: 150.939235ms
#3 error: "docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental not found"

docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental not found
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 1
```

Laptop Docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:39 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Cloud Build Docker Version:

```
Step #0 - "Version": Client:
Step #0 - "Version": Version: 18.09.7
Step #0 - "Version": API version: 1.39
Step #0 - "Version": Go version: go1.10.8
Step #0 - "Version": Git commit: 2d0083d
Step #0 - "Version": Built: Thu Jun 27 17:56:17 2019
Step #0 - "Version": OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Step #0 - "Version": Experimental: false
Step #0 - "Version": 
Step #0 - "Version": Server: Docker Engine - Community
Step #0 - "Version": Engine:
Step #0 - "Version": Version: 18.09.3
Step #0 - "Version": API version: 1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
Step #0 - "Version": Go version: go1.10.8
Step #0 - "Version": Git commit: 774a1f4
Step #0 - "Version": Built: Thu Feb 28 05:59:55 2019
Step #0 - "Version": OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Step #0 - "Version": Experimental: false
```

Update: I noticed that I was using #syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental whereas the linked article has #syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental.  I get the same error when using 1.0-experimental.

Comment: [Google Cloud example of using secrets in a build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials)

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the link.  However, that approach doesn't address the problem I'm trying to solve by using the --secret flag.  I'm building a Node application with a private package and need to pass an NPM_TOKEN to the docker build command. Using environmental variables and ARG in the Docker file will expose the token. See https://www.alexandraulsh.com/2019/02/24/docker-build-secrets-and-npmrc/ for the solution I'm trying to implement.

Comment: @Mark did you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, not.

Answer (score 14):

There seems to be an issue when the "registry-mirrors" option is used in combination with buildkit, then the buildkit frontend images fail to fetch:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39120

Pulling them before doing the build seems to resolve the issue:

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['pull', 'docker/dockerfile:experimental']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['pull', 'docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental']
```

Comment: THIS. Thank you @troels-liebe-bentsen. However, now getting this problem: 

    [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:12.18.4-alpine
    resolve docker.io/library/node:12.18.4-alpine 0.1s done
    ERROR: docker.io/library/node:12.18.4-alpine not found

Comment: this seems no longer needed. All that was needed for me was adding "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1"

Comment: @SamStoelinga can you show where you added that? as an `env`? or as `args`?

Comment: I think I did it as env variable like the OP in question did and it just worked

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue and managed to figure it out. It's not really possible to use docker buildkit with `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker`, instead, you have to run a docker in docker daemon and run another docker build on the side with docker-compose.

Specifically, you'll need a `docker-compose.yml` that has:

1. docker (docker in docker daemon)
2. a docker build step that builds the image (with buildkit enabled)
3. a docker auth and push step that authorizes docker to push to gcr (you need to create creds.json w/ service role w/ gcs permission, see bottom for details)
   In order to auth and push to gcr, one needs to do docker login with creds.json. See details: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

```
# deploy/app/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  docker:
    image: "docker:18.09.9-dind"
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - docker-certs-client:/certs/client
      - docker-certs-ca:/certs/ca
    expose:
      - 2376
    environment:
      - DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs
    networks:
      - docker-in-docker-network
  docker-build:
    image: docker:18.09.9
    working_dir: /project
    command: build -t 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<image>:<tag>'
    privileged: true
    depends_on: 
      - docker
    volumes:
      - docker-certs-client:/certs/client:ro
      - ../../:/project
    environment:
      - DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs
      - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
    networks:
      - docker-in-docker-network
  docker-push:
    image: docker:18.09.9
    working_dir: /project
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c
    command: 
      - |
        cat creds.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io
        docker push 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<image>:<tag>'
    privileged: true
    depends_on: 
      - docker
    volumes:
      - docker-certs-client:/certs/client:ro
      - ../../:/project
    environment:
      - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376
      - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    networks:
      - docker-in-docker-network
volumes:
  docker-certs-ca:
  docker-certs-client:
networks:
  docker-in-docker-network:
```

Then in your `cloud-build.yaml`:

1. you need to first decrypt a creds.json (must be created and encrypted first) -- for details: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
   (The push step will use the key to authorize docker login to gcr.)
2. Run a docker daemon from docker-compose in daemon mode (so it doesn't block the build and push step)
3. Run the build step `docker-compose`
4. Run the auth and push step in `docker-compose`.

```
# cloud-build.yaml
steps:
  # decrypt gcloud json secret
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
    - kms
    - decrypt
    - --ciphertext-file=deploy/app/creds.json.enc
    - --plaintext-file=creds.json
    - --location=global
    - --keyring=<...>
    - --key=<...>
  # run docker daemon
  - name: 'docker/compose:1.24.1'
    args: ['-f', 'deploy/app/docker-in-docker-compose.yml', 'up', '-d', 'docker']
    env:
      - 'PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID'
  # build image
  - name: 'docker/compose:1.24.1'
    args: ['-f', 'deploy/app/docker-in-docker-compose.yml', 'up', 'docker-build']
    env:
      - 'PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID'
  # docker auth and push to gcr
  - name: 'docker/compose:1.24.1'
    args: ['-f', 'deploy/app/docker-in-docker-compose.yml', 'up', 'docker-push']
    env:
      - 'PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID'
timeout: 600s
```

Comment: jesus that's a lot more than i expected it to be

Comment: Is this still the only option?

Answer (score 3):

I find solution:

1. You need add in your Dokeckerfile before FROM `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4`
   Info:https://www.docker.com/blog/image-rebase-and-improved-remote-cache-support-in-new-buildkit/
2. In step build add  `env: 'DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1'`

exmaple:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/prj-123-23231,'.']
  dir:  ubuntu
  env: 'DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1'
```